# Which should be used in ABAP : TYPE or LIKE?

Tags: abap

So these both seem to work for me:

```
TABLES:
  T001,        "Table of Company Codes.
  Z_KNA1_VBRK. "View I created..

DATA:
  CCNAME TYPE T001-BUTXT,   
  CCCURR TYPE T001-WAERS,   
  KNAVBK TYPE Z_KNA1_VBRK,
  AMNICC TYPE Z_KNA1_VBRK-NETWR.
```

and

```
DATA:
  CCNAME LIKE T001-BUTXT,   
  CCCURR LIKE T001-WAERS,   
  KNAVBK LIKE Z_KNA1_VBRK,
  AMNICC LIKE Z_KNA1_VBRK-NETWR.

PARAMETERS:
  COMPCODE LIKE T001-BUKRS.
```

Is there any difference between them technically? Which is preferred / best practice and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the difference try to compile the following program.

```
REPORT zzz.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: ls_t000t TYPE t000,
          ls_t000l LIKE t000.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

The error message you will get is

> Within classes and interfaces, you can only use "TYPE" to refer to ABAP Dictionary types, not "LIKE" or "STRUCTURE".

This is because in the OO context you need to write explicitly `TYPE` when you actually refer to a type. This is the current state of the art.

Now change your program slightly and try to declare global variables with `LIKE` and `TYPE`.

```
REPORT zzz.

DATA: gs_t000t TYPE t000,
      gs_t000l LIKE t000.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: ls_t000t TYPE t000.
*         ls_t000l LIKE t000.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

As you can see there are no compilation errors in this case. In this context `TYPE` and `LIKE` are interchangeable, they mean the same. This applies also to the "old" parts of ABAP means of modularization like subroutines and function modules.

However I use the following rule of thumb.

Whenever I refer to a DDIC or local type I use `TYPE`. If I want to create a variable that is exactly of the same type like other variable I use `LIKE`. Should the type of the original variable change in the future, the change has to be made only in one place then.

Example.

```
METHOD main.
   DATA: ls_t000t TYPE t000. "should the type change from T000 to T002
                             "in the future, one has to change it only in one place.
   DATA: ls_t000l LIKE ls_t000t.
ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: Nevertheless, it should be noted, such using of `LIKE` (with dbtables) is also [obsolete](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenlike_obsolete.htm) and is treated like **bad pratice**.

Comment: That's why I didn't even know such use-case:) Because I have never used it.

Comment: Amen to that. This is why I wrote that I use `LIKE` only when I refer to another's variable type and not to an explicit type.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a difference. 
You cannot get this difference because you declared your structures via `TABLES` statement, which is *obsolete* now and shouldn't be used.
[TABLES](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abaptables.htm) statement declares interface work area with a name **identical to** Data Dictionary structure. 
Therefore both your LIKE and TYPE declarations treat `Z_KNA1_VBRK` either like data object or DDIC structure correspondingly.
In any other case such declaration won't compile because LIKE and TYPE statements **are not interchangable**.
You should declare separate structures in your program rather than using such obsolete elements. The only allowed exception is data exchange with classic dynpros.
To further details, switch to [ABAP documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abaptypes_referring.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not completely true. In old program parts like reports, procedures or function modules the `TYPE` and `LIKE` could be used interchangeably, however I prefer `TYPE` when I explicitly refer to a DDIC or local type and `LIKE` when I want to create a variable of exactly the same time like other variable.

Comment: @Jagger, give an example, where they could be used interchangeably.